# Uploading a wear 2.0 android app

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

The [android dev docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#distribution-to-2-0) state:

> Distribution to Wear 1.x and 2.0 watches If you are already
>   distributing your app to Wear 1.x watches, follow these steps:
>
> - Provide a Wear 2.0 (standalone) version of your watch APK that can be made available in the Play Store on Wear.
> - Continue embedding a Wear 1.x APK in your phone APK, for use by watches that do not have Wear 2.0.

Later [the same docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#specifying-app-as-standalone) state:

> Wear 2.0 requires a meta-data element in the Android manifest file of watch apps, as a child of the  element. The name of the meta-data element is
>   `com.google.android.wearable.standalone` and the value must be `true` or
>   `false`. The element indicates whether your watch app is a standalone
>   app.
>
> ...
>
> If a watch app depends on a phone app, set the value of the above
>   meta-data element to false. Setting the element to false signifies
>   that the watch app should be installed only on a watch that is paired
>   with a phone that has the Play Store.
>
> Note: Even if the value is false, the watch app can be installed
>   before the phone app is installed.

The first makes it seems as though Wear 2.0 only supports standalone versions of a wear apk. The second makes it seem like I can have a Wear 2.0 app in which the wear module depends on the mobile module.

Furthermore, with the `com.google.android.wearable.standalone` set to `false`, I could not select the "Distribute your app on Android Wear" checkbox (under the "Pricing and Distribution" tab) when uploading my app. Changing it to `true` allowed me to check the box. In both cases I uploaded 2 apks (one mobile embedded with the 1.x wear apk and one wear 2.0 apk).

Does this mean I can't publish a Wearable app if it isn't standalone?